# Are there purely isolating/analytic languages with grammatical gender?

Tags: morphology, gender, isolating-languages, analytic-languages, agreement

It seems that all the things which reflect [grammatical gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender) in languages have to do with inflectional (presumably also agglutinative) morphology, such as agreement.

But is that just coincidence, it seems the same kind of thing could be reflected in particles in an isolating language. But does it ever happen? Are there [isolating/analytic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolating_language) with the concept of grammatical gender in nouns (not just natural gender in pronouns)?

Comment: How about [classifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_%28linguistics%29) in Chinese and other East/Southeast Asian languages?

Comment: @ZhenLin: [Classifiers are different to genders and noun classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(linguistics)#Noun_classifiers_vs._noun_classes) but they are often discussed together. I better mention this...

Comment: Have you read about [Khasi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khasi_language)?

Answer (score 9):

The WALS<sup>1</sup> lets you cross-classify languages based on two features.  Here's a link to the [cross-tabulation](http://wals.info/feature/combined/20A/31A) of "fusion of selected morphological formatives" and "sex-based and non-sex-based gender systems"<sup>2</sup>.  It indicates that there are 3 languages that fall into the "exclusively isolating, sex-based gender" class and one in "exclusively isolating, non-sex-based gender."  (There are mixed categories that you might wish to explore as well.)  You can follow up with these languages and see if they live up to their classification – some of them could have grammatical complications that make them less than pure examples of what you are looking for.

---

<sup>**Footnotes**</sup>
<sup>1. World Atlas of Linguistic Structures</sup>
<sup>2. The feature names are admittedly a little opaque.</sup>

Comment: Nice! I've never WALS before and found it a bit counterintuitive, but the language turned out to be [Supyire (or Suppire), a Niger-Congo language of Mali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supyire_language). Apparently it has "eight noun classes that are grouped into five noun genders" which I find surprising! The Wikipedia page doesn't say the language is isolating or analytic and does mention some affixes so I wonder if it's a perfect fit?

Comment: @hippietr: mentioning "affixes" is not yet incompatible with the idea of an "isolating/analytic" language, if they are derivational rather than grammatical (=inflectional). It would make sense to distinguish languages with no grammatical (=inflectional) categories, i.e. categories **obligatory** for being expressed. The language you've found may belong to the type of isolating/analytic language in this sense. Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolating_language : "which ... may change the meanings of individual words with derivational morphemes, [which] gives more than one morpheme per word".

Comment: @imz: Yes I'm a bit fuzzy on that because the isolating languages I'm a bit familiar with don't see have "real" affixes. Chinese, Thai, Vietnamese. They do have some things which some people call affixes but which other people seem to be able to explain some other way.

Comment: Is gender always expressed with a bound morpheme?   If not, wouldn't the Chinese classifier system be comparable to a gender system?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann: See Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(linguistics)#Noun_classifiers_vs._noun_classes